# Upload, create new directory, fetch local url, set field - PHP + MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I searched the whole internet about this. But, I can't get the answer. I'm still a beginner and I'm still studying about php+Mysql.

I've created a form consists of a picture, person name. After the 'submit' button clicked, the php and mysql script will create a new directory in local folder (public_html/images/$name/). The new created folder in images folder should be named as the person name (without space). Then, the folder address will be fetched and put into a column in phpMyAdmin table. For example, a guy named Bill filled in his data in the form. He uploaded his picture (rockstar.jpg) and put his name 'Bill Fish' in the form name field. Then, after he submit it, the script will create a new folder (/images/Bill_Fish/) and put his picture (rockstar.jpg) in it. After that, the folder address (/images/Bill_Fish/rockstar.jpg) will be put into a text field in a column in phpMyAdmin table.

form_post.php code

```
            $name= $_POST["name"];


            $file= "images/$name/";

            **I'm stuck here**
```

form.php code

```
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><input name="pic" type="file" id="pic" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="132"><span class="order">Name: </span></td>
              <td><span class="order">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
              </span></td>
            </tr>
```

Could anyone help me with this script? Sorry for asking for the script but I've searched all over the web and I couldn't get the answer.

Thank you very much. Really appreciate your help :D

Comment: You can ready how to upload files with PHP http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp 
how to use MySQL http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp and str_replace http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php to clean the directory name

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts I would like to give:

1. just replacing spaces my an underscore might not be enough, provided the users can input more or less anything as a name. Use a propper encoding instead, I suggest `url_encode()` and `url_decode()`, since paths behave close to urls. Just think of names like "Jon O'Hara" or "Nguy§/../äßt*+''s" being entered...
2. usually your task is solved different: you create a database entry for the user, for that entry an id is generated. Typically this is an auto incremented numerical index, that way you avoid problems with two accounts sharing the same name (happens...) and 'exotic characters'. You take *that* id as a name of the directory to be created. That way it is easy later to find that folder again. When you identify the right entry in the database you can construct the folders path without the need to have it stored. This also has the advantage that the folder structure you are to generate step by step is not hard coded. Instead you might come to the conclusion that you want to reorganize it. With reconstructing the path you only have to change the reconstructin algorithm, whilst when you store the final path you have to change all paths inside the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
$name= $_POST["name"];
$name = str_replace(' ', '_', $name); // replace space with underscore

$file= "images/".$name."/";
mkdir($file);

$filename = $_FILES['pic']['name']; // getting name of file being uploaded. Eg - rockstar
$ext = pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // getting extension of file being uploaded
$destination = $file.$filename.'.'.$ext; // this will be images/Bill/rockstar.jpg

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'], $destination))
{
   echo 'File uploaded successfully';
}
else
{
   echo $_FILES['pic']['error'];
}
```

Note that this is give you a general idea about file uploads. Of course steps should be taken to make sure only pictures are uploaded, file size limit etc.

Forgot `mkdir`. Thanks to Tiit for bringing that up

Answer (score 0):

first of all: the form should be with the right `enctype` to upload files:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="form_post.php" method="POST">
<input name="name" type="text"><br />
<input name="pic" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

secondly lets look at the PHP side. To get the file data, you'd have to look at $_FILES array. All information regarding the image would be in `$_FILES['pic']`. In that array there are elements like 'name' (name of the file) and 'tmp_name' (temporary name of the uploaded file).

What you want to do is the following: 
Create the folder:

```
$name = str_replace(" ","_",$_POST['name']); // replace space with an underscore
$dir = "images/".$name;
mkdir($dir);
```

move the temporary file to the right folder:

```
$tmp_name = $_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'];
$name = $_FILES['pic']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $dir."/".$name);
```

and You should have yourself a solution that you described.